# How to increment apk version without keystore

Tags: android, google-play, android-manifest, android-keystore

I am currently facing an issue in production with an apk and unfortunately I don't have the keystore and password that has been used to sign it (it belongs to a 3rd party that I am not able to contact at the moment). Moreover, Google doesn't allow me to fallback to the previous version of my apk due to various restrictions (which are not worth to explain here).

However, I have an old signed apk that works, so I would like to increment the manifest version, and upload it again on the Google Play. I don't want to modify anything else than the version number and version code. Is this possible without using the keystore? If so.. how?

Comment: If the apk is signed I guess it could not be possible

Comment: If this was possible, there would be no security in Android.  Think about it.  Anyone could update any app.